# Lunatic Cultist won’t spawn

Tags: terraria

I've done everything but nothing works. We’ve defeated the Golem but he won’t spawn not even the table is there!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just to confirm, which platform are you on? PC?

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean the [cultists](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cultist) that appear on the entrance to the dungeon aren't spawning. The [Lunatic Cultist](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lunatic_Cultist) is the boss that spawns when you kill them.

First things first: The Lunatic Cultist is only available on the PC, Xbox one and Playstation 4. If you're not on one of these platforms, then you simply can't fight the boss. Sorry.

Assuming you're on one of these platforms, there are some things you can try:

- Try beating the Golem again. Who knows, maybe a bug caused it to not register properly (something like this once happened to me, when the [Dryad](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dryad) wouldn't spawn after beating the [Eye of Cthulhu](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eye_of_Cthulhu). Beating it again solved the problem)
- The cultists won't spawn if you placed walls in the dungeon's entrance. If you did, make sure you destroy them using a hammer.
- If there's a [Meteorite](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteorite_(biome)) nearby, [Meteor Heads](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Meteor_Head) will prevent the Cultists from spawning. Make sure to mine the meteorite away.
- The cultists won't spawn while you are in the dungeon. To be sure, you can wait near the [World Spawn Point](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Spawn), or in the jungle, which are guaranteed to be far enough away.

If you did any of the above and they still didn't spawn, try restarting the world (by closing and opening it again). Finally, make sure no [events](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Events) are happening and no [bosses](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bosses) are alive when checking if they spawned.

Answer (score 1):

Also if there is a hole or you broke some of the entrance they won’t spawn. Try going deep into the dungeon and getting some bricks and fill it in

Answer (score 0):

possibly you have some wiring up to a teleporter, if you do try moving it somewhere else but still close to the dungeon in order to make room for them to spawn, this happened to me, hope this helped

Comment: Maybe you could clarify what worked for you- any specific details about how you were able to set it up would help. Be aware though, this question is very general and most likely can't be answered due to its low quality.